'luarocks' doesnt find the executable even if i specify
I've already searched everywhere
nothing helped me
literally nothing
Like, I've never programmed in LUA before, but I'm having trouble installing luarocks on Windows
luarocks is not finding the executable, as mentioned in the title
Error: Lua 5.4 interpreter not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1

Please set your Lua interpreter with:

   luarocks --local config variables.LUA <d:\path\lua.exe>

I have already specified the path several times and still nothing
I noticed two files were missing, in different directories
I wrote them both in --local and normal
luarocks config variables.LUA "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe"

and it appears
Wrote
        variables.LUA = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\5.1\\lua.exe"
to
        C:\Program Files\luarocks\config-5.4.lua

same as local
Wrote
        variables.LUA = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\5.1\\lua.exe"
to
        C:\Users\POSITO\AppData\Roaming\luarocks\config-5.4.lua


the files luarocks.exe and luarocks admin.exe are in the folder along with the interpreter
even with all this, there is still the error

Error: Lua 5.4 interpreter not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1

Please set your Lua interpreter with:

   luarocks --local config variables.LUA <d:\path\lua.exe>

is the same error
and yes, i typed luarocks for see and i always see this part

Configuration:
   Lua:
      Version    : 5.4
      LUA        : (interpreter not found)
                   ****************************************
                   Use the command

                      luarocks config variables.LUA <d:\path\lua.exe>

                   to fix the location
                   ****************************************
      LUA_INCDIR : (lua.h not found)
      LUA_LIBDIR : (Lua library itself not found)

   Configuration files:
      System  : C:\Program Files\luarocks\config-5.4.lua (ok)
      User    : C:\Users\POSITO\AppData\Roaming\luarocks\config-5.4.lua (ok)

   Rocks trees in use:
      C:\Users\POSITO\AppData\Roaming\luarocks ("user")

if this question is marked as a duplicate of another question that helped me in no way, I will quit the forum because I hate the forum and I'm being forced

i will try unninstall and install it again

Ok
I just unninstalled Lua and Luarocks anyways and worked too.
This forum was completely unnecessary to post >:(

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
